# AWS Destination not working and I dont know why

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have manually tested an AWS Lambda using the "Test" button available in the AWS Lambda functional panel.
This lambda function does not require any input data/event infromation.
It works great...

My problem:

I am trying to call this function with another AWS Lambda through the use of destination, and it's simply not working.

How can I check if destination is firing ?

I have it set up for asynchronous, invoke on success.

## Lambda(success) -> call perfect(Lambda 2)

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "it's simply not working"? Any errors?

Comment: It's simply not working, I get no errors so I can't troubleshoot. First Lambda finishes with success, second lambda does not even log to cloudwatch print(event).

Comment: And I don't think its an IAM issue because it would not let me add AWS Lambda as a destination if the roles were not correct

Answer (score 3):

For the asynchronous destination to work, you need two things:

1. **Execution role** for the first function allowing it to `invoke` destination function.
2. First function **must** be invoked asynchronously. For this you need to specify  `invocation-type` as  **Event**.

For example, to call it from the command line:

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name name_of_first_function \
    --invocation-type Event \
    --payload '{"message": "Hi"}' /dev/stdout
```

Comment: I did both things, and it's still not working. Going through aws support now